# How to build recursive menu with unique ID in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to build a menu tree with id like below, I tried below code for first build a tree but doesn't return the expected output.
Can anyone help how to do this?

Below is just an example of how the items could get arranged with id

```
<ul>
    <li id = "1">Office</li>
    <li id = "2">Home
        <ul>
            <li id = "2-1">Bed</li>
            <li id = "2-2">Pillow</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id = "3">School
        <ul>
            <li id = "3-1">Class
                <ul>
                    <li id = "3-1-1">Grade</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

List<Node> _nodes = new List<Node>();
_nodes.Add(new Node() { id = 1, parentid = 0, name = "Office" });
_nodes.Add(new Node() { id = 2, parentid = 0, name = "Home" });
_nodes.Add(new Node() { id = 3, parentid = 2, name = "Bed" });
_nodes.Add(new Node() { id = 4, parentid = 2, name = "Pillow" });
_nodes.Add(new Node() { id = 6, parentid = 0, name = "School" });
_nodes.Add(new Node() { id = 7, parentid = 6, name = "Class" });
_nodes.Add(new Node() { id = 8, parentid = 7, name = "Grade" });

private static string RenderMenu(List<Node> nodes)
{
    StringBuilder menu = new StringBuilder();

    if (nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        menu.AppendLine("<ul>");
        foreach (Node _n in nodes)
        {
            menu.AppendLine("<li>");
            if (_n.parentid != 0)
                menu.AppendLine(RenderMenu(nodes.Where(p => p.parentid == _n.parentid).ToList()));
            else
                menu.AppendLine(_n.name);
            menu.AppendLine("</li>");
        }
        menu.AppendLine("</ul>");
    }
    return menu.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a tree structure but you draw it as a plain structure.

I mean your `foreach (Node _n in nodes)` will make as many `<li>` as you have items in your `List<Node>`. It is not what you want.

It would be more logical and convenient to pass `id` instead of `List<Node>` as you need the whole `List` at every moment of time since you don't know which items will be presented in the next sub-menu.

Now about unique ID. I would recomment using the same `id`s as you have in your `List<Node>`. It is easier and it is guaranteed that they are unique (otherwise, we simply cannot build a menu). You need to store the full path to it. 
There is a good option - to pass an array \ `List` with `id`s as function argument. However, global `Stack<int>` with `Node` `id`s is a great option. 
Every time you are "entering" a node - you add it to stack, every time you "leave" it - you remove one item. At every moment, you have the actual recursive path.

That's how I would solve this problem:

```
public static List<Node> _nodes;
public static Stack<int> _currentPath;

public static string RenderMenu(int id)
{ 
    var currentChildNodes = _nodes.Where(x => x.parentid == id).ToArray();
    if (currentChildNodes == 0) return String.Empty; // No children - no submenu!

    StringBuilder menu = new StringBuilder();
    menu.AppendLine("<ul>");

    foreach (var currentChildNode in currentChildNodes)
    {
        _currentPath.Push(currentChildNode.id);
        menu.AppendLine(String.Format("<li id='{0}'>{1}{2}</li>", 
            String.Join('-', Array.Reverse(_currentPath.ToArray())),
            currentChildNode.name, 
            RenderMenu(currentChildNode.id));
        _currentPath.Pop();
        // Keep in mind that if currentChildNode does not have child nodes
        // then RenderMenu() will return String.Empty and result will be "<li>name</li>"
    }

    menu.AppendLine("</ul>");
    return menu.ToString();
}

// Somewhere in code
RenderMenu(0);
```

If, for some reason, you need to generate a consequent `int` id, you can change the loop this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentChildNodes.Count; i++) // Convert to for-loop
{
    var currentChildNode = currentChildNodes[i];
    _currentPath.Push(i + 1); // Change node.id to i
    menu.AppendLine(String.Format("<li id='{0}'>{1}{2}</li>", 
        String.Join('-', _currentPath.ToArray()),
        currentChildNode.name, 
        RenderMenu(currentChildNode.id));
    _currentPath.Pop();
    // Keep in mind that if currentChildNode does not have child nodes
    // then RenderMenu() will return String.Empty and result will be "<li>name</li>"
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works :)
but how to generate it with dynamic ID (1,1-1,1-1-1)

Comment: Thanks , id generation part not 100% work as expected .
e.g : for the parent (id = 2) child return as 0-2 and 0-0-2 not like 2-1 and 2-1-1. 
i try to do something with your help ,please check whenever you get a chance.

Comment: @RuwiniDayaratne How about changing it to (i + 1)? Check my update, please.

Comment: It returns the id string with its letters reversed 1-3,1-1-3,2-1-3,3-1-3 
not like 3-1 ,3-1-1 ,3-1-2

Answer (score 1):

```
string menu = OrganizeMenu(_nodes);

private static string OrganizeMenu(List<Node> nodes)
{
    menu.Append("<ul>"); // start the List
    List<Node> parentNode = nodes.Where(item => item.parentid == 0).ToList(); // Get all Parent Node (Root Node i.e. a Node with parentid = 0)
    List<Node> childNode = nodes.Except(parentNode).ToList(); // Get all Child Node (i.e. a Node with parentid != 0)

    foreach (var pNode in parentNode) // traverse for each Parent Node and add this to root level
    {
        menu.Append("<li>"); 
        menu.Append(pNode.name);
        GetChilds(nodes, pNode);
        menu.Append("</li>");
    }

    menu.Append("</ul>"); // end the list

    return menu.ToString();
}

private static void GetChilds(List<Node> nodes, Node parentNode)
{
    List<Node> childs = nodes.Where(item=> item.parentid == parentNode.id).ToList();
    foreach (var child in childs)
    {
        menu.Append("<ul>");
        menu.Append(child.name);
        GetChilds(nodes, child);
        menu.Append("</ul>");
    }
}
```